# 500 error in Heroku, when Debug=False

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

I know that this questions has been asked numerous times but after going through pretty much every thread I could find, I am still struggling to make sense of my problem. I have a django project on heroku which works perfectly fine as long as I set the setting variable debug=True. https://dry-depths-69493.herokuapp.com/

However, once I have set it to False, I get a 500 error. I have checked the settings.py which has:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['dry-depths-69493.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1',"localhost", "0.0.0.0", ".herokuapp.com"]
```

I have set unset all unnecessary env variables in Django and only added

```
COLLECTSTATIC:     1
```

And I also have included Whitenoise and added dj_database_url. Does anyone have another idea, what could be the reason for these issues? Unfortunately the logs just say that it is a 500 error but give no specifics. Here is the github-link:
https://github.com/Datenrausch/heroku

Comment: Have you run it on a development server?

Answer (score 1):

To have more debug information, I would login into the heroku dyno using heroku-cli and the command `heroku run bash` and then run Django webserver with `./manage.py runserver`. This way you should already see if there is something wrong.

If it works normally, then run it on the background (`./manage.py runserver &`) and try to access the homepage with `wget localhost:8000`. At this point you should have the 500 error debug information.

Comment: Thanks Ludo, but unfortunately, this is all I get...

`python3 manage.py runserver&wget localhost:8000
[1] 11
--2018-06-15 06:01:32--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... failed: Connection refused.
~ $ Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'honoradar' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem but I'd start addressing the warning: you are including `honoradar.urls` for two different urls in your `mysite/urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a WhiteNoise X Heroku problem. I fixed the issue by using the approach of this post:

[Django Debug=False whitenoise not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952467/django-debug-false-whitenoise-not-working)

Crucial thing seems to be this part in settings.py:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```